# PDE development: How to find out where a plugin from my target platform originates from?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pde, target-platform

In my eclipse project I have set a target platform via target definition file.

I've noticed that a specific plug-in is present in two different versions: 1.7.9 and 1.7.2. I checked this by doing "Window -> Show View -> Plug-in Development -> Target Platform State" and search for the plug-in name.

Both versions appear and they are located in `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\plugins`

I want to get rid of 1.7.2, but when I open the target definition file it does only refer to the 1.7.9 version:

```
<unit id="slf4j.api" version="1.7.9"/>
```

How can I find out where the plug-in originates from, in order to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use version="0.0.0" which say use the latest version of the plug-in available.
See this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394788) and explanation [here](https://www.bsiag.com/scout/version0-0-0-in-target-platform/)

---

### About content.jar / content.xml

`"content.xml" and "artifacts.xml" contain metadata for the exported files.`

Read **p2 concepts** section in the blog [p2 updates for Eclipse RCP applications](http://www.ralfebert.de/archive/eclipse_rcp/p2_updates_tutorial_36/) for more details.

Check these links

- [update site](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fupdate_site.htm)
- [classic vs p2 update site](http://plosquare.blogspot.in/2009/05/migrating-eclipse-update-sites-to-p2.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It's not exactly what I want. I rather want to prevent that any updatesite or other mechanism is providing the older version of the plugin. And I can't find which updatesite is providing the plugin. So how can I find out?

Comment: post your target file.If not possible visit repository in browser download content.jar unzip it then in the content.xml file search your plugin, do this for all your repos in target file

Comment: Thanks. Your comment actually was the answer I was seeking for.

Comment: Would you mind to edit you question to include the essence about content.jar / content.xml - then I would be happy to accept the answer.

Comment: @MichaelS edited my answer please check. Accept if it is OK else edit your question.